# chrome ruins layout made by masonry-plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, jquery-masonry

You can see it in action here:

http://maenhaut.wordtgetest.be/index.php?a=nl&b=home

sometimes it's alright, it shows as it's supposed to. [image: as it should be]
But after a refresh (or two) you will see it's displayed completely wrong. [image]

In safari and firefox it works like it should be. Does anyone have a fix or clue why this happens?

Comment: checked with FF .... running completely nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called the masonry-function in the $(document).ready function. So before some of the images have loaded. I changed it to $(window).load, and then it works fine. [More information here](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/).